# Grouping elements in AngularJS using filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can someone tell me of grouping the elements from an array inside an array using **groupBy** in angularjs.

Suppose I have JSON data like this:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "country_list": [{
      "_id": {
        "_id": "100",
        "country": "UAE",
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "_id": "101",
        "country": "India",
      }
    }
  ],
  "city_list": [{
      "_id": {
        "_id": "11",
        "country_id": "101",
        "city": "Chennai",
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "_id": "10",
        "country_id": "100",
        "city": "Dubai",
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "_id": "11",
        "country_id": "101",
        "city": "Mumbai",
      }
    }
  ],
  "port_list": [{
      "_id": {
        "_id": "20",
        "city_id": "11",
        "ports": "Chennai Port"

      }
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "_id": "21",
        "city_id": "10",
        "ports": "Dubai Port"
      }
    }, 
    {
      "_id": {
        "_id": "22",
        "city_id": "11",
        "ports": "MumbaiPort"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And I am supposed to get the following result:

- India

  - Mumbai

    - Mumbai port
  - Chennai

    - Chennai Port
- UAE

  - Duabi

    - Dubai Port

I have tried using `GroupBy()` but end with some random orders. Any Help would be Appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what's groupBy and how did you use it? Your question is incomplete.

Comment: The best way would be rewritting your JSON from your server instead of doing the grouping on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use nested `ng-repeat` with `ng-if` conditions in order to show related items by `_id`s

But notice that in the provided JSON data you have two cities Chennai and Mumbai with the same `_id` and that may give you unexpected results

Code:

```js
angular
  .module('App', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', function () {
    var vm = this;
    vm.data = {"status": "success","country_list": [{"_id": {"_id": "100","country": "UAE",}}, {"_id": {"_id": "101","country": "India",}}],"city_list": [{"_id": {"_id": "9","country_id": "101","city": "Chennai",}}, {"_id": {"_id": "10","country_id": "100","city": "Dubai",}}, {"_id": {"_id": "11","country_id": "101","city": "Mumbai",}}],"port_list": [{"_id": {"_id": "20","city_id": "9","ports": "Chennai Port"}}, {"_id": {"_id": "21","city_id": "10","ports": "Dubai Port"}}, {"_id": {"_id": "22","city_id": "11","ports": "Mumbai Port"}}]};
  });
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.10/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="App">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="DefaultController as vm">
    <ul ng-repeat="country in vm.data.country_list | orderBy: '-_id._id'">
      <li>
        {{ country._id.country }}
        <ul ng-repeat="city in vm.data.city_list">
          <li ng-if="country._id._id == city._id.country_id">
            {{ city._id.city }}
            <ul ng-repeat="port in vm.data.port_list">
              <li ng-if="city._id._id == port._id.city_id">
                {{ port._id.ports }}
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```